# How to express the result of a conversion?

Tags: expressions

"With this converter, one can convert A to B." Then the result of that conversion from A is B. How to attribute B later to let others know it was converted from something else?

1. Converted B can be used to do something.
2. B, as the conversion result from A, can be used to do something.

Sentence 1 sounds like B is the object that was just converted. And Sentence 2 is too long and I don't know if it is appropriate to say "conversion result".

A and B are conceptions from programming or software. For example, to convert an `integer` to `float`.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, that A could be a liquid measure expressed in litres and B the same quantity expressed US gallons? If so you could say "A, expressed as B, can be used to calculate fuel consumption in a manner meaningful to American motorists"

Comment: A and B are conceptions from programming or software. Updated the question.

Comment: Are you changing the definition of the variable without changing its value or are you creating a new variable with a different name and moving the new value to it? That is if you defined a variable **price** of type **currency** so that it only had two decimal places then passed it to your function would the function return **price** of type **float** or would it return a new variable (**taxedPrice**, say) of type **float** containing the value of **price** but capable of being multiplied by a non-integer tax rate and not having its decimal places truncated?

Comment: A and B are basically different kind of things. For example, A is a solid box (13cm*12cm*10cm) made of steel and B is a solid box made of copper. But the shape (13cm*12cm*10cm) of B is sampled from A. An *imaginary* converter takes A and converts it into B.

Comment: Regard the converter as a function, a black-box.

Comment: You seem to be Posting about some specialized language, perhaps dedicated to maths, philosophy or programming and in any case, not English.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't know how to properly express my idea in English, so I came here for an answer.

Comment: @zwcloud I understand that but what does the function return?

Answer (score -1):

I think the  result of conversion can be just 'a convert'. According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
convert noun
con·​vert | \ˈkän-ˌvərt  \
Definition of convert
: one that is converted.
I realize the noun has a strong religious reference, but the new meaning may appear via the metaphorical transfer in the actual context.

Comment: A convert is a person ('one' in the definition) converted to another religion.